# Blazor InputNumber set value to 0 when emptied

Tags: html, asp.net-core, blazor

When I cleared the value in the `InputNumber` control by pressing the delete button and then press the tab button, the value remains unchanged and is not updated.

The property I bind the `InputNumber` control is as follows

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,6}$", ErrorMessage = "The Price field cannot have more than 2 decimal places.")]
public decimal Price {get;set;}
```

How can I make it so that when I press the delete button, `Price` is updated to 0?

The reason I want to make this happen is that the current behavior is causing some issues.
Here is an example:

1. In the setter of the `Quantity` property, when `Quantity` is set, if `Quantity` and `Price` are not 0 then set `Unit Price` to `Price` divided by `Quantity`
2. Set `Price` to 100
3. Delete `Price` by pressing the delete button. **Error message** screams `"The Price field is required."` but the value for `Price` remains as 100
4. Set `Quantity` to 10. `Unit Price` is incorrectly calculated into 10. Despite the fact that empty is being displayed instead of 100 on the `<InputNumber>` control for `Price`.

I have tried:

1. Using `@OnEmptied` on the `<InputNumber>` control => Doesn't update the value for `Price` either
2. Making `decimal` into `decimal?` This doesn't help much as I still wants to validate if `Price` is entered

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Full code below (index.razor):

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<EditForm Model="item">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    <div>
        <label>Quantity:</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="item.Quantity"></InputNumber>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>item.Quantity)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Unit Price:</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="item.UnitPrice"></InputNumber>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>item.UnitPrice)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Price:</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="item.Price"></InputNumber>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>item.Price)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>

</EditForm>

@code {
    private Item item = new Item()
    {
        Price = 0,
        Quantity = 0,
        UnitPrice = 0
    };

    public class Item
    {
        private decimal _quantity;
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,6}$", ErrorMessage = "The Qauntity field cannot have more than 6 decimal places.")]
        public decimal Quantity
        {
            get => _quantity;
            set
            {
                _quantity = Math.Abs(value);

                if (_unitPrice == 0 && _quantity != 0 && _price != 0)
                {
                    _unitPrice = decimal.Round(_price / _quantity, 6);
                }

                if (_quantity != 0 && _unitPrice != 0)
                {
                    _price = decimal.Round(_quantity * _unitPrice, 2);
                }
            }
        }

        private decimal _unitPrice;
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,6}$", ErrorMessage = "The Unit Price field cannot have more than 6 decimal places.")]
        public decimal UnitPrice
        {
            get => _unitPrice;
            set
            {
                _unitPrice = Math.Abs(value);

                if (_quantity == 0 && _unitPrice != 0 && _price != 0)
                {
                    _quantity = decimal.Round(_price / _unitPrice, 6);
                }

                if (_quantity != 0 && _unitPrice != 0)
                {
                    _price = decimal.Round(_quantity * _unitPrice, 2);
                }
            }
        }

        private decimal _price;
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,6}$", ErrorMessage = "The Price field cannot have more than 2 decimal places.")]
        public decimal Price
        {
            get => _price;
            set
            {
                _price = Math.Abs(value);

                if (_quantity == 0 && _price != 0 && _unitPrice != 0)
                {
                    _quantity = decimal.Round(_price / _unitPrice, 6);
                }

                if (_unitPrice == 0 && _price != 0 && _quantity != 0)
                {
                    _unitPrice = decimal.Round(_price / _quantity, 6);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `InputNumber`, and `Quantity` code?

Comment: @ConnorLow Sure! I have added the full code.

Comment: By "press the delete button", do you mean you are clearing out the input content, or is there a keyboard event tied to the `Delete` key that you aren't divulging?

Comment: Also, should the regular expression for `Price` be `^\d+.\d{0,2}$`? Your error message doesn't match otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your regular expression (`^\d+.\d{0,6}$`) doesn't match the desired behavior you are describing. Break it down:

- `^\d+`: begin with one or more decimal numbers *<sub>so far so good</sub>*
- `.`: one of any character *<sub>Danger! Your input now needs to be at least 2 characters long!</sub>*
- `\d{0,6}$`: 0-6 decimal characters at the end *<sub>ok</sub>*

So `10`, `0.`, and `0d` will all match, but `0` does not. You don't have to worry about some of those since you are using a number input, but you probably want the ability to insert a single digit number. Change your regex to `^\d+(?:\.\d{0,6})?$`:

- `^\d+`: begin with one or more decimal numbers *<sub>still good</sub>*
- `(?: ... )?$`: optional group to end with (so the decimal is optional) *<sub>good.</sub>*
- and the grouped `\.\d{0,6}` (`\.\d{0,2}` for price): one litteral "`.`" followed by 0-6 decimal characters. *<sub>good!</sub>*

As for setting the input to '0' after deleting its contents, this is easily done with JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form input[type="number"]')
  .forEach(input => {
    // input or keyup events will work
    input.addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => input.value = target.value || '0')
  })
```